# Spark 1.5.2 and Hadoop 2.4 (Hive 2) version compatibility

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, version

I am new in using Spark with Hadoop.

**Current Scenario:**

I have already configured Spark on 4 node cluster using pre-built binary "spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6".

There is also one Hadoop-2.4 cluster with 4 nodes present in my environment.

**What I want:**

I am planning to use Spark RDD processing using Hive HQL on the data present in hdfs in Hadoop cluster.

**Queries**

1. Do I need to reconfigure spark cluster using  "spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4" binary or the current one will work.
2. Is it a good practice to work on Spark over Hadoop with Spark and Hadoop on two different clusters (but under same subnet in cloud).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the best practice would be to run spark and hadoop on the same cluster. In fact, spark can run as a yarn application (if you do spark-submit with --master yarn client).
Why ? It boils down to data locality.
Data Locality is a fundamental concept of hadoop and data systems in general. The general idea is that the data you want to process it's so big so rather than moving the data, you'd rather move the program to the node the data resides on. 
So, in the case of spark, if you run it on a different cluster, all the data will have to be moved from a cluster to another through the network.
It's more efficient to have computation and data on the same node.

As for version, having two hadoop clusters with different versions can be a pain. I'd recommend you have 2 different installations of spark, one per cluster, compiled for the appropriate version of hadoop.

Comment: Thanks Roberto for the answer. Yes, I understood the best practice would be to use Spark and Hadoop as per locality concept. One more question as I am a bit curious to understand it clearly, the data

Comment: Sorry question was not complete. I am curious to understand it clearly, Even if the HDFS data and Spark processing is in different cluster in this system, the performance will be better compared to the system with only Hadoop map reduce processing on HDFS data in the same cluster, Right? i.e the Spark in-memory computation overcomes the network latency which is due to data migration between clusters, Right?

Comment: That depends on the type of computation and on the quantity of data you are processing.
Let me clarify. Each job has different characteristics and hence may have a different bottleneck. 
For instance, if you're processing a very large input (let's say, 10 Terabytes of apache logs) to calculate simple statistics, the data size is going to make data locality more important than in-memory processing. If you're running an iterative algorithm like k-means, in-memory is more important than data locality.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the concept. There are two usecases of using Spark in my environment. 1. Applying machine learning algorithms using Sparkling water (H2O library over Spark) on hdfs data. The data used in this case is not that big, it will be of around 100-600GB (less than a TB). So, Spark in memory will perform better in this case (Spark nodes with 64 GB memory and 16 cores ). I also understand that will depend on the type of algorithm I will be using.  2. Get the data from a external data source and apply some computation (Spark streaming) and store the results in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the compatible versions of spark with hadoop.

As is recently got to know, you can refer to the compatibility chart here : 
http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/asparagus-chart-hdp24.png